# Auto scrolling content in Windows 10 UWP app development

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I am new in UWP app development. I would like to know what are the alternative of Android `TextSwitcher` and `ImageSwitcher` control in Windows UWP app development platform.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement similar functionality using a [`FlipView` control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/flipview), which works asa a "carousel" for any content type.

There are two other nice options as part of the open-source UWP Community Toolkit. [`RotatorTile` control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/rotatortile) automatically flips through assigned content items, similarly to a live tile in the Start menu. Finally, the [`Carousel` control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/carousel) is a classic carousel of items. This probably suits your use case the least of the three, however.

Comment: Good luck with your app:-)!

Comment: can you please help me with this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712483/uwp-command-bar-with-custom-image